# Commercial OSM Overpass server

Tags: cloud-service, gis

I am looking for a reliable hosted Overpass server where I can pay for N requests per sec/hour/day. I looked at https://switch2osm.org/providers/, and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM-based_services , and googled, but did not find any. I found several for geocoding (Nominatim), but nobody offers overpass API. Public servers have low limits for use and not very reliable.

I posted this Q previously on GIS exchange, but it was closed: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253080/commercial-osm-overpass-server. I hope it is inline with "Software Recommendations", in this case I am looking for software in the cloud.